# How can i specify invalid dates as an interval from ,to in a p-calendar in angular?

Tags: angular

I have a p-calendar in angular where i want to specify invalid dates within in interval of dates starting from today  to a today+10 without counting weekends in the interval.

Please how can i proceed to do it ?

HTML:

```
   <p-calendar [(ngModel)]="value" [inline]="true" [locale]="calendar_fr"
  [minDate]="today"
        [disabledDays]="[0,6]"
        [maxDate]="maxdate" ></p-calendar>
```

this is the ts code

```
value= Date;
today = new Date();
maxdate = new Date();

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.maxdate.setDate(this.today.getDate() + 10);
             }
```

Comment: Mind sharing the code?

Comment: Sure i will add it

Comment: So i want to disable dates from today to today+10 without including Weekends

Comment: how can i specify interval of invalid dates in p-angular and excluding week ends from it ?

Comment: You have to bind the `[disabledDays]` to a variable in your typescript file.

Comment: yes but i have already disableDays that disable week ends in all the calendar.

Comment: Can you show me with some code please?

Comment: I am not getting your question properly. You have disabled days of the weekends? What you want to do then?

Comment: i have a p-calendar  i have disabled week ends for all the months in the calendar but i want also to disable an interval  from today to today +10  without counting week ends in the interval

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like this

HTML

```
[disabledDays] = "myDisabledValues"
```

TS

```
value= Date;
today = new Date();
maxdate = new Date();
myDisabledValues : any [] = [];

ngOnInit(): void 
{
  this.maxdate.setDate(this.today.getDate() + 10);
  
  for(var i = today; i < maxdate; i++)
  {
       this.mydisabledValues = i;
  }
}
```